# Computing the sum of each column in a matrix returns the same result for every column

Tags: java, for-loop

This is supposed to add up all elements of each column and give the sum for each. When I run it, it just gives the same answer for each column. Am I missing something?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumColumnElements {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] matrix = new double [3][4];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter " + matrix.length + " rows and " + matrix[0].length + " columns:");
    for (int row = 0;row < matrix.length; row++) {
      for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {
        matrix[row][column] = input.nextDouble();
      }
    }
    sumColumn(matrix,0);
  }
  public static double sumColumn(double[][] m, int columnIndex) {
        double total = 0;
        for (int column = 0; column <= columnIndex; column++) {
          total = 0;
          for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
            total += m[row][column];
           //System.out.println("The sum for column "+column+" until row "+row+" is " + total);
          }              
         System.out.println("The sum for column "+ column + " is " + total);            

        }
        return total;
}
}
```

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: You placed four println commands right after each other; since `total` is not changed between these lines, the same value is used in every output. There should be just one println command, and the index of the column (0,1,2,3) should not be coded in but rather taken from the `column` variable.

Comment: Try something like `System.out.println("The sum for column " + column + " is " + total);` and remove the other 3.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing all the values right after each other. what do you expect the outcome of:

```
System.out.println("The sum for column 0 is " + total);
System.out.println("The sum for column 1 is " + total);
System.out.println("The sum for column 2 is " + total);
System.out.println("The sum for column 3 is " + total);
```

to be? This is going to print the string followed by `total` four times back to back, and the value of total isn't changing from one line to the next.

This should probably be a single line:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] matrix = new double [3][4];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter " + matrix.length + " rows and " + matrix[0].length + " columns:");
    for (int row = 0;row < matrix.length; row++) {
      for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {
        matrix[row][column] = input.nextDouble();
      }
    }
    System.out.println(sumColumn(matrix,3));
  }

public static double sumColumn(double[][] m, int columnIndex) {
    double total = 0;
    for (int column = 0; column <= columnIndex; column++) {
      total = 0;
      for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
          total += m[row][column];
      }
      System.out.println("The sum for column " + column + " is " + total);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Input:

`1 2 3 4`

`5 6 7 8`

`9 0 1 2`

Output:

```
The sum for column 0 is 15.0
The sum for column 1 is 8.0
The sum for column 2 is 11.0
The sum for column 3 is 14.0
14.0
```

I would also be remiss if I didn't point out that your method name is "sumColumn" and has a single return value of `double`. If you want this to return only a single column's total you should rethink the parameters you're passing in and the way in which you're totaling all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

you should write the print statement only once as it will print once for each column loop. Secondly if you are getting the same answer that means you output is printed for the first loop of outer `for` with same value and then your outer loop stops. check what the value of `columnIndex` is. try the code below

```
   double total = 0;
for (int column = 0; column <= columnIndex; column++) {
  total = 0;
  for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
    total += m[row][column];
  }
  System.out.println("The sum for column " +  column  + " is " + total);
}
```

Comment: That gives the sum for the first column, which is what I had already. I need the other three column sums.

Comment: @ChristopherBasinski that is because your outer loop is not running after first column, pls check what is `columnIndex` value because that is the max limit for loop to run.

Comment: I added the rest of the program, isn't the columnIndex stated in the main method, or do I have to move it?

Comment: @ChristopherBasinski when calling `sumColumn(matrix,0)` you are passing `columnIndex` 0 which is first column index. Hence outer loop stops at that value. change it to `sumColumn(matrix,3);`

Comment: Thank you, I shouldn't have limited the issue to the sum method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this what your code should be if you are trying to print sum of each column( until x rows)

```
public static sumColumn(double[m][n] data) {

        for (int column = 0; column < m; column++) {
          // store the total value of column
          double total = 0;
          for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
            total += data[row][column];
           //System.out.println("The sum for column "+column+" until row "+row+" is " + total);
          }              
         System.out.println("The sum for column "+ column + is " + total);            

        }
}
```

Update: This should print the total for each column provided a doublematrix.
Instead of printing if you want to return the data to callee method store in an array total[] at respective column index

```
public static double[] sumColumn(double[m][n] data) {

          // store the total value of column..default will be 0
          double total[] ;
        for (int column = 0; column < m; column++) {

          for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
            total[column] += data[row][column];
           //System.out.println("The sum for column "+column+" until row "+row+" is " + total);
          }              
         System.out.println("The sum for column "+ column + is " + total[column]);            

        }
   return total;
}
```

Here "0" means 1st column and so on till "m-1" means m column

Comment: That still just gives 1 column.

Comment: @ChristopherBasinski I reworked it have a look at it now

Answer (score 0):

The program looks correct to me for most parts. Here are some minor tweaks:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumColumnElements {

  public static final int ROW = 3;
  public static final int COLMN = 4;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] matrix = new double [ROW][COLMN];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter " + matrix.length + " rows and " + matrix[0].length + " columns:");
    for (int row = 0;row < matrix.length; row++) {
      for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {
        matrix[row][column] = input.nextDouble();
      }
    }
    sumColumn(matrix, COLMN);
  }
  public static double sumColumn(double[][] m, int columnIndex) {
    System.out.println("columnIndex: " + columnIndex);
    double total = 0;
    for (int column = 0; column < columnIndex; column++) {
      total = 0;
      for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
        total += m[row][column];
      }
      System.out.println("The sum for column "+ column + " is " + total);
    }
    return total;
  }
}
```

For a particular input:

```
1  2  3  4

5  6  7  8

9 10 11 12
```

Output will be:

```
The sum for column 0 is 15.0
The sum for column 1 is 18.0
The sum for column 2 is 21.0
The sum for column 3 is 24.0
```