# 2D Array: How do you find the largest column sum and return that column index?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, max

```
  public int largestColumnSum(){
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i=0;i<array[0].length;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++){
           sum += array[j][i];
```

I got to this part but I have no idea what to do after. How should I find the largest column sum and return the index of that column?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this

```
public int largestColumnSum(){
    int index = -1, sum = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        int tempSum = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++)
            tempSum += array[i][j];

        if(tempSum > sum) {
            sum = tempSum;
            index = i;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check out this link this is similar to your question but just need to return the column index 
[Computing the sum of each column in a matrix returns the same result for every column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328142/computing-the-sum-of-each-column-in-a-matrix-returns-the-same-result-for-every-c)